# Selection boxes as features

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

In my database there are the following fields, which take either 0 or 1 to represent true or false to state whether the feature is available:

```
feature1
feature2
feature3
feature4
```

All of these correspond to an available checkbox in my PHP page that allows for selecting a feature.

Each element looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature1" value="1">
```

I then set this to a variable, and if the checkbox isn't ticked, it sets the variable to 0:

```
$feature1 = $_POST['feature1'];
if ($feature1 != '1'){$feature1 = 0;}
```

There are more selections than just features (such as number of players, date etc.) as it's for a booking system. If a feature is not selected then all fields matching the other criteria should be displayed, as well as everything with the feature available and not available. So in a way, similar to this:

```
if ($feature1 = 1){
[SHOW ONLY SPORTS WHERE FEATURE1 IS TRUE AND OTHER CRITERIA IS TRUE]
}
else {
[SHOW ALL SPORTS WHERE OTHER CRITERIA IS TRUE, FEATURE1 BEING TRUE OR FALSE DOES NOT MATTER]
}
```

Here's my query to the database (ignore mysql_* - I understand the risks, but it's not relevant in this case, please don't bash).

```
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sport WHERE players = '$players' AND room_type='$rm_type' AND feature1='$feature1'");
```

This is fine when the user DOES want feature1, but if they don't mind whether feature1 is true or false (as it's an additional option), it will only display where feature1 is false. It should display everything where feature1 is true OR false.

Obviously I could do this as:

```
if ($feature1 == 1){
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sport WHERE players = '$players' AND room_type='$rm_type' AND feature1='$feature1'");}

else {
$test = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sport WHERE players = '$players' AND room_type='$rm_type'");}
```

However, with multiple separate features, it'd take lots of if statements, with lots of possible mysql queries.

Is there any way for me to get around this? Say for example, a user has selected that they want feature 2 and feature 4, it should show all results where feature 2 and 4 are TRUE, and feature 1 and 3 are either TRUE or FALSE.

Hope this makes sense. Any pointers into techniques that could help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: That is relevant here, the risk is not only on `mysql_*` library, the risk is the fact you're directly using the variables on the query without using any sanitization and can also happen on PDO and MySQLi so make sure you sanitize your data using [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or prepared statements depending on the library in use!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this maybe?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sport WHERE players = '$players' AND room_type='$rm_type'";
if ($feature1 == 1){
   $sql = $sql . " AND feature1='$feature1'";
}
if ($feature2 == 1){
   $sql = $sql . " AND feature2='$feature2'";
{
if ($feature3 == 1){
   $sql = $sql . " AND feature3='$feature3'";
{
if ($feature4 == 1){
   $sql = $sql . " AND feature4='$feature4'";
{

$test = mysql_query($sql);
```

alternately you could try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sport WHERE players = '$players' AND room_type='$rm_type'
        AND (feature1='$feature1' OR '$feature1' != '1')
        AND (feature2='$feature2' OR '$feature2' != '1')
        AND (feature3='$feature3' OR '$feature3' != '1')
        AND (feature4='$feature4' OR '$feature4' != '1')";
$test = mysql_query($sql);
```